# Sensor to track book open or not

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

For my project, I need to develop a gadget to track if a given book is open or not. Can any one help me what kind of sensor I need to use and the full configuration manual of that sensor. I tried, Proximity sensor from http://popular.ebay.com/business-industrial-k-z/proximity-sensors.htm this page, but I have no idea about how to give power supply to them. Can any one tell me about a sensor that can work with a coin cell (Maxell Batteries)

note : I am a very beginner to sensors.

Comment: If I wanted to know if a book was open I'd use my eyes - I can even tell what page it was open at.

Comment: @Andyaka Good joke but, I am expecting better answers.

Comment: Then you better start asking a better question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with a proximity sensor. Those are intended to see how far an object is, without touching. In a phone, it's used to measure if your face is close enough to the screen that the screen should turn off.

Needing to know if a book is open or not is so much simpler. Like the way the iPad can tell if the case is closed or not. It uses a magnet and a hall effect sensor. A magnet with a small reed switch can also work.

A simple flex sensor in the spine could work. A light dependent resistor or photoresistor can work as well. Or the simplest method, two pieces of metal that only touch if the cover is closed (A normally closed momentary switch).

Comment: This is what exactly I am searching for. Yes I am already using the switch you told. But I need a sensor. And thanks again for the answer.